# Amplify backend pull failed in web host app

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

We have set the CI/CD pipeline in amplify and since 22nd Dec the backend build is getting failed and throwing the error "Failed to pull the backend" as per the attached screenshot,

[image]

**Expected behavior:** The build should be successfully completed. Here I'm attaching the last successful build screenshot,

[image]

I tried to redeploy the last successful build, but that also failed and gave the same error.

version details,
**Node.js:** 16.18.1
**Amplify CLI Version:** 10.5.2
**OS:** Amazon Linux 2

NOTE: The project is working fine locally, and also the amplify pull command runs successfully. In local I'm using windows.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you ever use this command after you set CI/CD pipeline in your project or make any changes in your amplify environment?

Comment: @Tolga No. I used to run it on my local machine when setting up the project first time.